# Updating an array field columns in big query

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Problem statement :

How to update an array field in big query

Below is my table

```
Test_table
-------------------------------
file.fileName | file.count
-------------------------------
abc.txt.      | 100
-------------------------------
```

From the above table I need to update the both fileName and count fields

Schema:

```
{

  "name": "file"
  "type" : "record"
  "mode" : "repeated"
  "fields" :[
            {
               "name": fileName
               "type": string
               "mode" :nullable
             },
             {
               "name": count
               "type": string
               "mode" :nullable
             }
             ]  
}
```

can some one help me on how to execute update query on this table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't you do something like this?

```
update t
    set file[safe_offset(1)].filename = ?,
        file[safe_offset(1)].count = ?
```